# How to avoid "Sign in to iMessage" prompt in MacOS

Tags: messages

I am logged in to my Apple account in my Mac so that I can update apps in the App Store, but I an not logged in to iMessage nor Facetime because I do not wish to use them.

Whenever I log in to my Mac account, I get a **Sign In to iMessage** prompt to enter my password for my Apple ID.

I can always click Cancel, but I would like to not get the prompt at all (and I do not wish to sign in merely to avoid the prompt because I do not want any iMessage activity to happen in the background).

Is it possible to get rid of the **Sign In to iMessage** prompt when you wish to be permanently logged out?

Comment: Is the Messages app open? What app is the prompt appearing in. That prompt should only appear if you open Messages whiles signed out.

Answer (score 1):

You may have left the Messages app open. To close the app, locate it in the dock, then right-click to access the 'Quit' button. Alternatively, you can press ⌘+Q after clicking on the app icon in the dock. This occurrence is due to the default setting that reopens apps after logging back in. To disable this behavior, simply deselect the checkbox when logging out. After either disabling  app reopening or quitting the messages app, the sign in prompt should no longer appear.

This is the log out window with the checkbox:

[image: Log out window]